# Why can't I get the specific node under some condition?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

Why doesn't this xpath work with me? I want the current `title` if the `language _id =2`

```
./title[language_id=2]
```

---

```
<news pnumber="1" id="1"><event_id>578</event_id><event_type_id>1</event_type_id><language_id>2</language_id><title>meeting</title></news>



<news pnumber="1" id="1"><event_id>578</event_id><event_type_id>1</event_type_id><language_id>1</language_id><title>meeting</title></news>
```

Comment: then what is the right one :)

Comment: your query is for a title element with a language_id attribute of 2 - I think what you need to search for is the parent element then extract the title from it - afraid I dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct XPath expression is

```
//title[../language_id=2]
```

Answer (score 2):

**To avoid the reverse axis, use**:

```
self::*[language_id=2]/title.
```

Comment: Could u explain what do u mean by `reverse axis` please?

Comment: @just_name: Reverse axes are: `parent::`, `ancestor::`, `ancestor-or-self::`, `preceding-sibling::` and `preceding::`

Answer (score 1):

First add root to your XML then:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);

var result=  doc.Descendants("news")
             .Where(x=>x.Attribute("id") != null && x.Attribute("id").Value = "1")
             .Select(x=>x.Descendants("title").First().Value);
```

**Here is description of this linq2xml:**

First Load XML file (Also you can parse xml string):

```
XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
```

Find your `news` elements :

```
doc.Descendants("news")
```

Between `news` elements select elements which has `id=1`:

```
Where(x=>x.Attribute("id") != null && x.Attribute("id").Value = "1")
```

From each filtered item select first title:

```
x.Descendants("title").First().Value
```

Comment: Could u help me with `xpath`?

Comment: I think added descriptions is enough to understand it (if you are familiar a little with linq), linq2xml is faster and IMO more readable than xpath. Also possibility of bugs in linq2xml is smaller than xpath.

Comment: I need `xpath` because i use the following method :

`lbl_date.Text = XPathBinder.Eval((((lbl_date.NamingContainer as RadRotatorItem)).DataItem), "./title", "");`

Comment: @just_name So use Nico's answer